# Are hats like Red Shirt and Imitation Crab scaring off new Users?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

It might just be me, but the usual stream of marginally bad questions are being met with torrents of downvotes today, presumably because of the Hat Incentives to do same.

Although in no means am I condoning bad questions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481360/why-cout-outputs-wrong-chars-from-char-array) [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481413/how-to-make-like-this), these questions would otherwise receive perhaps one or two downvotes, and a comment encouraging more effort, more detail, or better google fu to avoid duplication of questions, etc.

However, today, it seems these questions are being aggressively downvoted to levels otherwise only seen in the realms of Spam or deliberate trolling.

Do we need to somehow reign in the clay pigeon shoot, or is this a deliberate shift in attention to stamp out bad questioning for once and for all?

**Edit**
Things appear to have settled down again - looks like everyone who wanted Red USS shirts and Crab ears have obtained same and have headed off to collect other hats.

Comment: Questions like the one you linked have **always** been getting a lot of downvotes.

Comment: "is this a deliberate shift in attention to stamp out bad questioning for once and for all?" - I think that's impossible, but I'd certainly welcome it. Don't see any harm in downvoting crap, but once a question hits -5 it's kind of a waste of votes to downvote it further. Better reserve the vote for another crap question, there's always more of them.

Comment: @Stuart I see nothign wrong with that, especially given that the OP is choosing to ignore the feedback - even though -9 is admittedly extreme, and it's well possible it's fuelled by the hats.

Comment: Hmm ... [walll of code is now nett -17](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481716/output-sheet-needs-the-name-of-origin-workbook) and closing in on the top 50 all time worst questions which haven't been deleted. Perhaps also need a Deletion hat to keep up with Red Shirt + Crab?

Comment: And admissions of [deliberate downvoting :-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488922/a-program-to-calculate-all-combinations-of-a-word)

Comment: My favourite part of Winter Bash 2014 so far has been discovering that the Community user is wearing an Imitation Crab hat. Don't take that away from me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The entire point of the hats feature was to increase user participation during the doldrums of Christmas.  That's working.

The number of upvotes have increased significantly.  Right now I see 25 posts with a score of +10 and up, that's roughly a 250% increase from the usual voting patterns.

Emphasizing the negative is a Meta hazard.

Comment: Yup, have climbed on the bandwagon and earned myself a pair of lobster ears. Hopefulyl no-one is taking this too personally.