# Are hats decreasing the quality of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

After reading the comments in [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277407/do-we-want-hats), [this particular post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277411/1237578) stood out to me.

I too am concerned that people will post rubbish, [cast useless or false votes](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/imitation-crab), [accept useless answers](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/naruto) or even [delete a good answer(!)](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/fear--loathing) just to gain useless hats.

Are hats decreasing the quality of Stack Overflow?

Comment: They are definitely decreasing the quality of meta.SO as every second question today is about hats...

Comment: I can't see why this question is downvoted. It's a concern about behavior of (some)/(a lot) users obvious to every one, not a rant about hats. While the hats have positive effects too, I can clearly see the downsides.

Comment: @bummi Probably because the same thing can be said about nearly any feature on SO: badges and even the reputation system *can* be used in a way to decrease quality. Such as the *Fastest Gun in the West* or *Robo Reviewers*. But hats unlike rep and badges are temporary. Hats are going to go away in a few days, so I doubt people will go to such limits to get a hat that will only last so long.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek maybe, but I did see things in a mass, I would not have thought possible.

Comment: @bummi: Hats are a seasonal way to *have a little fun* on a site that the rest of the year is quite serious (and strict about enforcing it). They're also discussed every year, both before the feature is started to make sure that users want it and during the course of the hat *season*. If someone is engaging in "rubbish" to gain hats, VTC and downvote as usual or flag the post for a mderator.

Comment: MathOverflow are not playing hats, but nonetheless [appear to be adversely affected](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2057/bizarre-recent-upvotes#2058)

Answer (score 26):

If you see any blatantly invalid behaviour and cheating to get hats, flag the behaviour for moderator attention. Hats are never an excuse to break the rules.

But *on the whole* I think that hats bring more fun, and much needed focus on quality (reviewing and handling bad questions is also rewarded with hats).

Comment: It also brings things like "post a question from the android app" - as if people don't already struggle enough when posting from a normal pc! I severely doubt that it's possible to ask a high-quality SO question from a smartphone...

Comment: I just saw 5 upvotes on a crapy question. probably to get the vote badge for today

Comment: @l4mpi: in the podcast they were talking about how surprising it was that people were posting so much from the mobile apps. Remember that the SE network is larger than just the programming sites; imagine working on your bike and tapping in a question on your tablet about how to adjust the gears on Bikes.SE. Personally, if I did have a high-quality question to ask, I'd email myself the question pre-formatted and paste it on my iPhone. The issue there coming up with a question to ask..

Comment: @juergend I see disproportionate amounts of upvotes on crap questions all the time, that doesn't neccessarily have anything to do with hats. Martijn, I see the value for other SE sites (e.g. ELL.SE, cooking.SE et cetera), but IMO asking from a phone could probably be disabled for SO without losing anything of value. I've been thinking about this for a while now (pretty much since the app was rolled out), maybe I'll post a related meta question some time.

Comment: Keep in mind that the vote requirement doesn't say it has to be an upvote.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The *Warm Welcome* hat presumably means you vote up, not down. :-)

Comment: Ah, yea, that one. But there would be no point in adding a 2nd (or 5th) vote to a new post.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Here's to hoping that only the *first* such vote counts.

Comment: Hm, I hope so too

Answer (score 13):

Partially, yes. In a way it is creating a virtual war/hunt for hats. Some people want to have hats and want to see their names on the leadership board. To achieve them they start doing creepy things. I think hats should bring more fun and also should improve the quality. Somethings like hats for upvotes/downvotes are leading so called "hathunters" (I term them so because they do everything to earn the hat) to downvote even good questions/answers and even upvote some shitty posts.

I observe these hats are encouraging people to actively use the site, but these should not mislead the actual essence of the site.

The hats should help people to learn new things. Hats for good questions from [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS)/[Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) is good, but hat for just posting from the app!! (I think the developers are using this hats system to make users download the app and make money).

I didn't mean to hurt any one. This is just my opinion on the current winter bash and the things going around it.

Answer (score 8):

Sure, the hats' goals could be interpreted as encouragement to misbehave on the SE network, but most goals are actually do-able by just using the network like you normally would.

- Imitation crab: 5 downvotes is not even close to what I usually vote,
- Fear & Loathing: I have plenty of bad answers that wouldn't suffer from being deleted,
- Naruto: A answer that receives no votes? Guess what kind of answer I've got most of...

Sure, people can go on a hat gathering rage and just post crap all over the place, but that's nothing the community can't (doesn't already) handle.

Source:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no doubt that hats certainly change the community's skyline for three weeks or so. Personally I don't believe this is a bad thing at all. It allows the boundaries to be pushed in various directions, which hopefully allows the SE team to peer into potential new behavioural gamification features / rewards / penalties in the future.

Things which stood out for me:

1. Secret hats [aren't as secretive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats) as they were in previous years - a good thing, as it reduces [random behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214893/149333)
2. It appears that the sheer volume of questions nowadays means that lazy + poor quality questions (and OP's) need to be snipped in the bud - tolerance is low for crappy questions.

- [Are hats like Red Shirt and Imitation Crab scaring off new Users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280296/are-hats-like-red-shirt-and-imitation-crab-scaring-off-new-users)

3. On the other hand, the chase for the elusive 30 minute Pizza hat has been quite comical:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27690915/why-do-i-get-a-compilation-error-with-this-declaration
- [Cannot convert traditional for loop to for-each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610117/cannot-convert-traditional-for-loop-to-for-each-loop)
- [Matching new lines not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27643418/matching-new-lines-not-working)
- [How to `std::bind()` a standard library algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694035/how-to-stdbind-a-standard-library-algorithm)
- And my [own feeble attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710789/is-there-a-discontinuity-over-year-end-in-datetime) was dismembered by the mighty Jon Skeet in a few seconds. <sub>("*Does anyone **other than** Jon want to add an answer?*")</sub>

Comment: [It's a slippery slope...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280456/2958086) Ironically, the best mileage for hats is on lower-traffic sites. I got Handegg on Academia, for example.

Comment: The thing I like about them (and I'm usually of the no-fun-no-celebration-antisocial persuasion) is that they remind me annually to get back into the habit of using up most or all of my daily reviews, hang out on meta if I haven't much recently, etc. In other words, instead of mostly just commenting to improve questions, I do _everything else too_.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest not bumping posts ___this old___ with an edit insulting SE users. It's gonna get looked at and reverted, any way.

Comment: Not insulting at all - it's pretty much the truth - ask any of the OP's linked. The Winterbash pizza hat required posting a question which gathered 5 answers in 30 minutes, which did attract some pretty interesting behaviour from those trying to obtain it.
You've been around long enough to have survived / endured / enjoyed a few Winterbashes!

Comment: Even if they agree, it's unfriendly to an outside observer, and completely unnecessary on a question that hasn't seen activity in _years_.