# Give an option to wear multiple hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014

This year for [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) in addition to hats we have things like "Red shirt", "Fascinating" etc... It would be great if there was way to wear "Red shirt" together with a matching cool hat :)

Could we get the option to wear multiple items (perhaps with some restrictions on combinations)?

**Update:** Not sure why this question was criticized so much, but my intention was just to share my wish, so all SO users' sake, and let everyone share in the fun. As a developer myself I know that sometimes it's to complex to develop a tiny thing, if that's the case then to point it out!

Comment: Come on, that would be just silly.

Comment: @Bart - If all are simply hats it could be silly. But this is something different ;)

Comment: Some hats would go well together... vulcan + (any other hat) for example...

Comment: @bart not at all, I could be wearing my star trek shirt with my iOS App beret! C'mon SO... "Make it So"!

Comment: Coding the feature to accept multiple hats would probably be *way* more coding effort than they are willing to expend, and would require major reworking of how they store the information. I think you'll just have to settle for the screen capture technique below.

Comment: It's not silly if you have multiple faces.

Comment: People with no faces are given the option to wear no hats. People with many faces should be given the opportunity to wear many hats, by extension!

Comment: @Bart Shame on you! You can never have too many hats :P

Comment: @Sammaye "You can never have too many hats"[*citation needed*]

Comment: No pain no gain, you can get all the hats!

Comment: just ignore the issue some hats wont go well with others, it's the same as when you get dressed, just a matter of style !

Comment: @Bart [Silly Hats Only](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEiyBbP28g8)

Comment: @Tanner Wups sorry my edit crossed yours, mea culpa!

Comment: @Jeroen no problem... we had the same _intenstion_...

Comment: I'm in no way an expert but isn't looking funnily silly (at least once a year) the whole point of this hat thing?

Comment: @Rikesh I agree with you. All Despicable Me Minions such as Rikesh and myself, unite to make this happen!

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c1/The_500_hats_of_bartholomew_cubbins.jpg

Comment: @AlexisDufrenoy That (looking intentionally silly) is why I changed my profile picture to a photo of David Cameron. Getting the "fear and loathing" hat was a nice bonus.

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2779909#2779909

Answer (score 142, accepted):

1. Wear a hat
2. Capture your profile image (using tool of your choice) wearing a hat
3. Upload new profile image of you wearing a hat
4. Wear another hat

Comment: I'm doing that already. Extra benefit: you can keep wearing your hat(s) after December. (I've been wearing last year's hat all year. :D)

Comment: This won't work well for hats going out of the box of the gravatar.

Comment: It will if you capture it @Awal (though that will make you smaller of course).

Comment: @AwalGarg still (or even more so), it's an out-of-the-box solution!

Comment: @Ben: can you recommend a tool I can use to capture my profile image?

Comment: balpha recommends a strategy in [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280494/458741) @Philip.

Comment: There should be a *multiple hat* contest http://stackoverflow.com/users/3063910/richard-scriven

Answer (score 170):

This is a slippery slope. First it'll be two hats, then three... and then before we know it, it'll be something like this...

Attribution: [Ashelang](http://ashlelang.deviantart.com/art/Every-Hat-In-TF2-401600741)

**[Scroll to bottom](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280393/give-an-option-to-wear-multiple-hats#comments-280456)**

[image: Every Single Hat in TF2]

**[Scroll to top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280456/2958086)**

Comment: It was a long scroll back up, but +1 xD

Comment: Good for you, the upvote button is on top. The comment section however...

Comment: [Here's a way back to the top](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280456/2958086). So meta.

Comment: @AwalGarg I have provided links both down and up to facilitate this.

Comment: Now THERE is someone with a CAN DO attitude. "Make it So" Stack.

Comment: You make this seem like it's a bad thing, when it's really quite awesome.  His neck must be stronger than steel to hold those things up, which is pretty cool in and of itself.

Comment: This deserves nothing but respect, but it must have taken you _ages_!

Comment: @Ben I didn't draw it. The artist has an attribution there <_<

Comment: This stack has overflowed

Comment: I've added scroll to bottom and top links in the post for you. :P

Comment: Very long hat is very long...

Comment: Viewing the list of revisions is even more fun. :)

Comment: What, no unicorn?

Comment: There should be a hat for just scrolling the full length, on a mobile device, within 30 minutes of your own Time Zone's New Year (i.e. under the influence). Quite a feat!

Answer (score 9):

Since I have two heads this would be perfect! I'm sick of being oppressed by the one-headed majority.

Answer (score 8):

Look, Ma! 2 hats

[image: Both my hats]

Open two tabs. One is your profile where you pick which hat to wear. The other is a question or answer where your reputation card shows up. Wear a hat. Wear a different hat. Don't update the page with your question or answer and you'll see each hat you've put on, at the same time! Even two of the same.

[image: Hella Hats]

I suspect you will all run into this message soon, so I'll go ahead and warn you.

[image]

Comment: that could deserve a hat

Comment: this glitch no longer works, sadly...