# How can I get a full resolution avatar including my partially transluscent hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014

The accepted answer to [**Give an option to wear multiple hats**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280393/1445366) suggests:

> 2. Capture your profile image (using tool of your choice) wearing a hat

However, my profile picture's resolution is 682x682 pixels, and taking a screenshot results in much lower resolution.

I tried right-clicking the hat, selecting *Copy Image URL* and got this:

```
data:image/svg+xml,<svg%20xmlns%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg"%20xml%3Aspace%3D"preserve"%20viewBox%3D"24.125%2032.25%20143.75%20127.5"%20version%3D"1.1"%20y%3D"0px"%20x%3D"0px"%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink"%20enable-background%3D"new%200%200%20200%20200"%20width%3D"92"%20height%3D"82">%0A%09%0A%09%0A%09%0A%09%0A%09%0A%09%09%0A%09%09%0A%09%0A%09%0A%09%0A<g%20transform%3D"%20translate(-12.829782960617933%2028.713500897940847)%20scale(1.0896599044867878)"><path%20d%3D"m97.4%20119.3c0.3-1.2%200-2.2-0.6-2.4l-24-6.1c0.6%200.2%200.9%201.2%200.6%202.4s-1%202-1.7%201.8l19.4%204.9c0.6%200.1%201.3-0.7%201.6-1.8l4.7%201.2z"%20fill%3D"%23E2DAC7"><%2Fpath><path%20opacity%3D".7"%20d%3D"m143.4%2079c-2.2-8.4-8.5-12.1-20.4-12.1-10.8%200-17%203.2-17.9%208.7-1.5%208.7%2011.4%2025.9%2029%2022.7%207.2-1.5%2012.5-7%209.3-19.3z"%20fill%3D"%23DC8427"><%2Fpath><path%20opacity%3D".7"%20d%3D"m56.6%2079c2.2-8.4%208.5-12.1%2020.4-12.1%2010.8%200%2017%203.2%2017.9%208.7%201.5%208.7-11.4%2025.9-29%2022.7-7.2-1.5-12.5-7-9.3-19.3z"%20fill%3D"%23DC8427"><%2Fpath><g%20fill%3D"%23EDC874">%0A%09<path%20d%3D"m70.2%20100.4c-1.5%200-3.1-0.1-4.7-0.4-4.3-0.8-7.6-2.9-9.6-6-2.4-3.8-2.8-9-1.2-15.5%202.5-9.2%209.5-13.5%2022.2-13.5%2015.6%200%2019.1%206.4%2019.7%2010.2%200.7%204.3-1.4%2010-5.5%2015-5.4%206.5-13.1%2010.2-20.9%2010.2zm6.7-31.7c-11.1%200-16.7%203.2-18.6%2010.8-1.4%205.4-1.1%209.7%200.7%2012.6%201.5%202.3%203.9%203.7%207.1%204.3%208.1%201.5%2016.4-1.8%2022.1-8.6%203.4-4.1%205.3-8.8%204.7-12-0.6-4.5-6.5-7.1-16-7.1z"><%2Fpath>%0A%09<path%20d%3D"m129.8%20100.4c-7.8%200-15.4-3.7-20.9-10.2-4.2-5-6.3-10.7-5.5-15%200.7-3.8%204.1-10.2%2019.7-10.2%2012.7%200%2019.8%204.3%2022.1%2013.5%201.7%206.4%201.3%2011.7-1.2%2015.5-2%203.1-5.3%205.2-9.6%206-1.5%200.3-3.1%200.4-4.6%200.4zm-6.7-31.7c-9.4%200-15.3%202.6-16.1%207.2-0.6%203.2%201.3%207.9%204.7%2012%204.8%205.7%2011.4%208.9%2018.1%208.9%201.3%200%202.7-0.1%204-0.4%203.3-0.6%205.7-2.1%207.1-4.3%201.9-2.9%202.1-7.2%200.7-12.6-1.9-7.6-7.4-10.8-18.5-10.8z"><%2Fpath>%0A%09<path%20d%3D"m100%2078.9c-3%200-5.5-2.5-5.5-5.5s2.5-5.5%205.5-5.5%205.5%202.5%205.5%205.5c0%203.1-2.5%205.5-5.5%205.5zm0-7.3c-1%200-1.8%200.8-1.8%201.8s0.8%201.8%201.8%201.8%201.8-0.8%201.8-1.8-0.8-1.8-1.8-1.8z"><%2Fpath><%2Fg><g%20fill%3D"%23E2DAC7">%0A%09<path%20d%3D"m147.7%2016.7c0-7.1-5.7-12.8-12.8-12.8h-69.8c-7.1%200-12.8%205.7-12.8%2012.8v6.4h95.5v-6.4z"><%2Fpath>%0A%09<polygon%20points%3D"147.7%2041.4%2098.8%2041.4%2052.3%2041.4%2034.7%2059.7%2098.8%2059.7%20165.3%2059.7"><%2Fpolygon>%0A%09<rect%20y%3D"23.1"%20x%3D"52.3"%20height%3D"18.3"%20width%3D"95.5"><%2Frect>%0A%09<%2Fg><rect%20y%3D"38.5"%20x%3D"52.3"%20height%3D"3.1"%20width%3D"95.5"%20fill%3D"%23BAB8A7"><%2Frect><rect%20y%3D"35.4"%20x%3D"52.3"%20height%3D"3.1"%20width%3D"95.5"%20fill%3D"%23CDC5B6"><%2Frect><rect%20y%3D"23.1"%20x%3D"52.3"%20height%3D"3.1"%20width%3D"95.5"%20fill%3D"%23BAB8A7"><%2Frect><rect%20transform%3D"matrix(.2455%20-.9694%20.9694%20.2455%20-60.61%20142.5)"%20height%3D"31.8"%20width%3D"4.4"%20y%3D"94.3"%20x%3D"59"%20fill%3D"%23E7E7E7"><%2Frect><ellipse%20rx%3D"2.2"%20ry%3D"1.2"%20transform%3D"matrix(.2454%20-.9694%20.9694%20.2454%20-68.44%20124.6)"%20cy%3D"106.3"%20cx%3D"45.8"%20fill%3D"%23943D24"><%2Fellipse><path%20d%3D"m68.2%20111.9c-0.3%201.2-1%202-1.7%201.8l9.5%202.4c0.6%200.2%201.4-0.7%201.7-1.8%200.3-1.2%200-2.2-0.6-2.4l-9.5-2.4c0.6%200.2%200.9%201.3%200.6%202.4z"%20fill%3D"%23DC8427"><%2Fpath><path%20d%3D"m80.1%20112.7l-2.9-0.7c0.6%200.2%200.9%201.2%200.6%202.4s-1%202-1.7%201.8l2.9%200.7c0.6%200.2%201.4-0.7%201.7-1.8%200.2-1.2%200-2.2-0.6-2.4z"%20fill%3D"%23D1AB62"><%2Fpath><rect%20y%3D"65"%20x%3D"77.4"%20height%3D"3.7"%20width%3D"45.1"%20fill%3D"%23EDC874"><%2Frect><%2Fg><%2Fsvg>
```

I pasted it into a new tab, zoomed to 500%, and got this:

[image: Fear and Loathing hat, zoomed in to 500%, in Google Chrome's Incognito Mode]

I could take a screenshot of that, and try to photoshop it, but then I'd lose the translucency in the sunglasses. So the accepted answer to that question doesn't work for this particular hat.

How can I get a full resolution avatar including my Fear and Loathing hat?

Comment: Looks like you'll need some mean photoshop skillz - try Stack Exchange Graphic Design: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I'd assume you need a program that can open the SVG image and convert it back to layers. I tried using the extension in Adobe Fireworks but it doesn't like the matrix transforms on the cigarette thing and doesn't create the shapes properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just save the hat to disk as an SVG file – either right-click -> "save image as" on the hat anywhere you see it, or "save as" (Ctrl-S or whatever it is on your OS of choice) when you're looking at what your screenshot shows.

Then use whatever image editing program you're using to open that SVG and combine it with your avatar.