# Apparently I can have multiples hats... sort of

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

I haven't noticed this behavior with any other hat I have, but when I select the Werewolf Hunter hat and choose "Wear hat", then go back into the hats area, I see a duplicate.

[image]

Any other hat I choose overlays the Werewolf Hunter hat.

[image]

Once I choose "Wear hat" again, only the last selected hat (such as the Bugdroid hat) overlays my profile pic.

Tested in Chrome 39.0.2171.71 and IE 11.

Comment: lol - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280393/give-an-option-to-wear-multiple-hats

Comment: Didn't work with my werewolf hunter hat :(

Comment: I just thought you'd set your avatar to one of the hats...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed now.

Your profile picture in the hat rack is a copy of the image that's visible in your profile anyway – when you open the hat rack, we just look for your profile's avatar image and create a duplicate of that in the "adjust your hat" area.

Unfortunately the selector to *find* your avatar inside the profile wasn't precise enough in some cases, and thus instead of finding your avatar, it would find its hat (which is an image as well) – and thus create a copy of your *hat* instead of your *avatar*.

Why did this only happen for the Werewolf Hunter? Well, one of the picture finding criteria in the not-precise-enough selector was that the image we're looking for has a width of 128 pixels. And with the way you have scaled and rotated your hat, that just happens to be precisely the width of the hat image when you wear the Werewolf Hunter – but not when you wear any other hat.