# Partner with a hat manufacturer and make realworld Winterbash hats orderable for money

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash

To get even sillier than outlined in [Give an option to wear multiple hats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280393/give-an-option-to-wear-multiple-hats), *and* to pick up the *excellent* stacked-hat-overflow answer there, *and* to give it a real good chance of being implemented in the most breathtaking way ever imaginable, how about StackExchange...

- partnering with a hat manufacturer so they'd design and offer users to order a real-world copy :) of any of their hats
- getting that manufacturer to build-to-order those hats, possibly with a personal    engravement/imprint/stitch-in, maybe using user's avatar image
- sending that hat to the OHO (original hat orderer) (and of course users can only order hats that they already own on-site)
- and, ultimately, sharing some of the wealth StackExchange is producing with the world by occassionaly serving such a real-world hat order away for free?

Now that would produce a sillyness overflow, so endlessly silly that it would re-spawn being ultimately cool.

It could even have an honest charity touch if StackExchange gave 1 (or whatever) buck per hat to some charity organization of their choice.

I believe a lot of users would order, and I am sure they would be willing to pay quite some money for such a unique hat. What the hat, I surely would.

Comment: I totally thought this was spam when I read the title...

Comment: I guess I know what to do for my Etsy store.

Comment: This is Hat Overflow.

Comment: We need a [money] tag on MSO for such posts. Whenever someone writes a post about real money, I miss the tag.

Comment: This is getting out of hand. Let's have shoes next year instead of hats.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Why?

Comment: Judging by how popular the virtual hats are, this could be a real money spinner for Stack Exchange.

Comment: "*I estimate a lot of users would order*" based on what? Most people are here for *free* advice, and don't even go out of their way to give a bit of their time to ask a good question, so what chances do we have of getting them to part with *money*? Also, a seasonal-only business model with only a short trading period has to be highly profitable to cover expenditure for the rest of the year. I doubt some hats would cater for such a requirement.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No shoes.... blue feet!!!

Comment: @bluefeet, your feet would make good secret shoes. Just saying.

Comment: @James replaced the undefendable estimation with -- personal belief.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [**Why can't Stack Exchange re-open the store?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147496/98786)

> The concept of *having* a store was much more attractive than folks actually had use for.