# Who thinks its a bad idea to get Hats by Downvoting?

Tags: discussion

Who thinks it's a really bad idea to have a feature where you can get a HAT on a website by down voting other posts?

Comment: You can also get a hat for downvoting *bad* questions. At least that encourages good moderation.

Comment: @SamIam:  There are no hats on per-site Metas.

Comment: bite me :)))))))

Comment: @SamIam It doesn't count on Meta :(

Comment: Watch the video

Comment: The video doesn't add anything to the question.

Comment: Can I get a hat for that?

Comment: You can get a flag and hopefully suspension if you keep editing in that video.

Comment: Why? Is that not cool?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280296/3651800

Comment: It's completely unrelated noise. If that's your idea of "cool" the I guess it's cool for you, but it certainly doesn't make it seem like you're seeking a serious discussion.

Comment: oh brother guys... joke! No fun... Ok.. Im deleleting this!

Comment: @l4mpi as opposed to all the other hat related jokes up here the last few days.

Comment: There's quite a difference putting a hat joke into a comment on a question and repeatedly editing a video link directly into a question, don't you think?

Comment: Not really... since I wrote the original post and thought it WAS relevant. And quite frankly who are you to decide what is relevant here?

Comment: Despite whatever you think, a video is certainly _not_ relevant for discussion about SO, unless maybe it directly shows your interaction with the site - and even that would be better expressed as text. And no, whatever pop culture reference that was (I didn't watch it and have no intention of doing so) does not magically make your question better, it just adds noise; and we've got quite enough noise on meta due to the winter bash already.

Comment: @l4mpi Im voting to close my own post... I don't need your ridiculous agro. If you can't take a joke I suggest you follow suit and close it as well... heck I might even get a hat for that :)

Comment: @CliffRibaudo I'm wearing the red shirt, and I'm pretty proud of it! Downvoting bad or off-topic questions, is an essentiall feature of this site, and I'm using it appropriately!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually so did I. Down Voting is an absolute requirement for proper site hygiene.

Comment: I've dwonvoted so much crap, I should be able to run a Millinery by now.

Answer (score 6):

At least, this year, the actions that I've had to do to get my hats have been entirely natural and not contrived.  Getting a hat for downvoting content isn't a bad thing, *especially* if the person downvoting the content is doing so because it is truly deserving of the downvote.

Besides, the hats are going to disappear in a few weeks anyway.  No one will really care if you got a hat for that action anyway.

My personal hope would be that one decides to take the *right* actions and votes where and when appropriate.